Why metric equivalence does not preserve completeness but norm equivalence does?
I was studying Functional analysis when I came across the normed space equivalence i.e. equivalent norms. I already proved that equivalent norms on a vector space $X$ over field $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ carry the same set of Cauchy sequences and that any sequence is either convergent with the same limit or is divergent in both the Normed Linear Spaces. and from this, we conclude that equivalent norms preserve completeness.
But while reading metric spaces, I came across an example of equivalent metrics defined by a bijection between two sets, say $A$ and $B$, where one was complete but another was not.
please, help me with this. I can not understand what is going on actually!
And exactly what condition we should impose so that the equivalent metrics preserve completeness? Or Does there exist any other types of metric equivalence which preserves completeness?
